# Julia: How to create a new column for each column of Number type?

Tags: julia

I wish to apply a function to all `eltype(col) <: Number` columns in a `DataFrame` and create a new column for each input column.

I am doing

```
f = identify # for example

function tmp(a)
    for n in names(a)
        if eltype(a[!, n]) <: Number
            a[!, n*"_binned"] = f(a[!, n])
        end
    end
    a
end

tmp(dataframe)
```

I feel there could be a more elegant way to do this in DataFrames.jl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think we have anything much better now. You could write:

```
foreach(pairs(eachcol(a)) do (n, c)
    eltype(c) <: Number && (a[!, n * "_binned"] = bincut(c, target))
end
```

or

```
insertcols!(a, [n * "_binned" => bincut(c, target) for (n, c) in paris(eachcol(a)) if eltype(c) <: Number]..., copycols=false)
```

but this is essentially the same (I would probably use `foreach`, I am showing you `insertcols!` just to show the API. `insertcols!` is a bit safer as `a[!, n*"_binned"] = bincut(a[!, n], target)` will silently overwrite an existing column while `insertcols!` will error if you have column name duplicate).